# TF 2.0 error with @tf.function decorator?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a very simple program with Python control flow statements

```
@tf.function
def mandelbrot(T, max_iter):
    for i in range(10):
        if (tf.abs(T)) >= 4:
                return 5
    return max_iter

T=tf.complex(10.,2.)
mandelbrot(T, 100)
```

But it is not working, and throws an error with massive trace. What's wrong with such a simple code?

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 T=tf.complex(10.,2.)
>         3 
>   ----> 4 mandelbrot(T, 100)
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
>       424     # This is the first call of **call**, so we have to initialize.
>       425     initializer_map = {}
>   --> 426     self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
>       427     if self._created_variables:
>       428       try:
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
>       368     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
>       369         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
>
> ## pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> --> 370             *args, **kwds))
>       371 
>       372     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
>   in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
>   **kwargs)    1311     if self._input_signature:    1312       args, kwargs = None, None
>   -> 1313     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    1314     return graph_function    1315
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
>   in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    1578           or
>   call_context_key not in self._function_cache.missed):    1579
>   self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
>   -> 1580         graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    1581         self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
>   graph_function    1582         return graph_function, args, kwargs
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
>   in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)    1510             arg_names=arg_names,
>   1511             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
>   -> 1512             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),    1513         self._function_attributes)    1514
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py
>   in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
>   func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
>   arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)
>       692                                           converted_func)
>       693 
>   --> 694       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
>       695 
>       696       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, IndexedSlices,
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
>       315         # **wrapped** allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
>       316         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
>   --> 317         return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
>       318     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
>       319
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py
>   in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>       684                   optional_features=autograph_options,
>       685                   force_conversion=True,
>   --> 686               ), args, kwargs)
>       687 
>       688         # Wrapping around a decorator allows checks like tf_inspect.getargspec
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py
>   in converted_call(f, owner, options, args, kwargs)
>       390     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs)
>       391 
>   --> 392   result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
>       393 
>       394   # The converted function's closure is simply inserted into the function's
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp95dcry6m.py in tf__mandelbrot(T, max_iter)
>        20     retval__1, do_return_1 = ag__.if_stmt(cond, if_true, if_false)
>        21     return retval__1, do_return_1
>   ---> 22   retval_, do_return = ag__.for_stmt(ag__.converted_call(range, None,
>   ag__.ConversionOptions(recursive=True, verbose=0,
>   strip_decorators=(tf.function, defun, ag__.convert,
>   ag__.do_not_convert, ag__.converted_call), force_conversion=False,
>   optional_features=(), internal_convert_user_code=True), (10,), {}),
>   extra_test, loop_body, (retval_, do_return))
>        23   cond_1 = ag__.not_(do_return)
>        24
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py
>   in for_stmt(iter_, extra_test, body, init_state)
>        79     return _dataset_for_stmt(iter_, extra_test, body, init_state)
>        80   else:
>   ---> 81     return _py_for_stmt(iter_, extra_test, body, init_state)
>        82 
>        83
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py
>   in _py_for_stmt(iter_, extra_test, body, init_state)
>        88     if extra_test is not None and not extra_test(*state):
>        89       break
>   ---> 90     state = body(target, *state)
>        91   return state
>        92
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp95dcry6m.py in loop_body(loop_vars, retval__1,
>   do_return_1)
>        18     def if_false():
>        19       return retval__1, do_return_1
>   ---> 20     retval__1, do_return_1 = ag__.if_stmt(cond, if_true, if_false)
>        21     return retval__1, do_return_1
>        22   retval_, do_return = ag__.for_stmt(ag__.converted_call(range, None,
>   ag__.ConversionOptions(recursive=True, verbose=0,
>   strip_decorators=(tf.function, defun, ag__.convert,
>   ag__.do_not_convert, ag__.converted_call), force_conversion=False,
>   optional_features=(), internal_convert_user_code=True), (10,), {}),
>   extra_test, loop_body, (retval_, do_return))
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py
>   in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
>       243   """
>       244   if tensor_util.is_tensor(cond):
>   --> 245     return tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
>       246   else:
>       247     return _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py
>   in tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)
>       254                                                         branch_name='else')
>       255 
>   --> 256   return control_flow_ops.cond(cond, protected_body, protected_orelse)
>       257 
>       258
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py
>   in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
>       505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
>       506                 instructions)
>   --> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       508 
>       509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py
>   in cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, strict, name, fn1, fn2)    1916   if
>   (util.EnableControlFlowV2(ops.get_default_graph()) and    1917
>   not context.executing_eagerly()):
>   -> 1918     return cond_v2.cond_v2(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)    1919     1920   # We needed to make true_fn/false_fn keyword arguments
>   for
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\cond_v2.py
>   in cond_v2(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
>        84                        true_graph.external_captures,
>        85                        false_graph.external_captures,
>   ---> 86                        name=scope)
>        87 
>        88
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\cond_v2.py
>   in _build_cond(pred, true_graph, false_graph, true_inputs,
>   false_inputs, name)
>       185     intermediate outputs.
>       186   """
>   --> 187   _check_same_outputs(true_graph, false_graph)
>       188 
>       189   # Add inputs to true_graph and false_graph to make them match. Note that
>
> ~.conda\envs\alphagpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\cond_v2.py
>   in _check_same_outputs(true_graph, false_graph)
>       584     error(str(e))
>       585 
>   --> 586   assert len(true_graph.outputs) == len(false_graph.outputs)
>       587   for true_out, false_out in zip(true_graph.outputs, false_graph.outputs):
>       588     if true_out.dtype != false_out.dtype:
>
> AssertionError:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like 2.0 can't deal with early conditional returns yet. I imagine that will be fixed at some point (feel free to check if there's a bug report/file your own), but in the mean time, the following works for me. It doesn't allow early exits, but it should give the correct result at least.

```py
@tf.function
def mandelbrot(T, max_iter):
    out = max_iter
    for i in range(10):
        if (tf.abs(T)) >= 4:
            out = 5

    return out


T = tf.complex(10.,2.)
m = mandelbrot(T, 100)
```

For multiple `T` values I think you'd have to resort to calling `tf.where`

```py
def mandelbrot(T, max_iter):
    ones = tf.ones(tf.shape(T), dtype=tf.int64)
    out = ones * max_iter
    fives = ones * 5

    for i in range(10):
        out = tf.where(tf.greater_equal(tf.abs(T), 4), fives, out)
    return out
```

You could do something more complicated with a `tf.while_loop` and `tf.TensorArray`, but I suspect there would be an overhead involved that would make things more expensive for small problems (and the code complexity would be non-trivial).

Note this isn't how the mandelbrot set is calculated - I'm assuming that's because you've reduced it to a minimal example. `T` is never updated here so you could remove the loop over `i`.

Comment: You're right, I decluttured the code to highlight the core of the problem. It says in the docs of 2.0 that it supports break, while and all major Python flow control statements. Anyway, I will just follow your fix for now. Thanks.

Comment: How do you make it work for batches of input? So T is not a single complex number but a entire list of them. Particularly, I fail when I compare it to 4. T>4 produces error, how to compare a tensor with a scalar, and the result of if condition depends on each single comparison !